# Facebook API version changes

Tags: facebook, api-versioning

I'm using Facebook API to create audience and upload data to created audience. But every time when Facebook changes API version, my web app show me logs that 'your ads API deprecated, change your API version'. And I know about these changes only after any error occurrence. How can I find out Facebook API version changes automatically? Or has any API that I can request every time and get fresh API version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upcoming changes are documented in the change log, usually way ahead of time:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Under https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/contact/ you can also specify what changes/events regarding APIs and your apps you want to be notified about, per email and/or notification on Facebook.